# How to override a function imported form other file in typescript?

Tags: typescript

i have a function named `getPerson`  declared in `msq.ts` file, In my `app.ts` file i just want to replace it with new implementation.

in my `msq.ts` file

```
export function getPerson(): Promise<{ name: string, id: number }> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ name: "manas", id: 2 });
        }, 5000);
    })
}
```

in my `app.ts` file

```
import * as msq from "../msq";


msq.getPerson = function():Promise<{name:string,id:number}>{
    return Promise.resolve({name:"manas",id:2});
}
```

but this is showing following error, when I try to replace the function

> can't assign to getPerson because it is a read-only property

Comment: Is it for testing? Which test framework/runner do you use?

Comment: To be honest it is for testing, as i am a newcomer in typescript i want to know how this could be done in TS, keeping aside testing framework. I use jest.

Comment: This is how you can do it in jest https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks. I don't think there's any valid scenario to do such a things in "real" code

Answer (score 0):

we can override the function if we wrap it with  object literal and export that object as default.

in `msq.ts` file

```
function getPerson(): Promise<{ name: string, id: number }> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ name: "manas", id: 2 });
        }, 5000);
    })
}

export default {
     getPerson
}
```

in `app.ts` file

```
import  msq from "../msq";

// now we can override the getPerson the way we want

msq.getPerson = function():Promise<{name:string,id:number}>{
    return Promise.resolve({name:"manas",id:2});
}
```

if we are doing this for unit testing (using jest) then we can easily mock it with `jest.fn()`

```
 import user from "../user";
 import msq from "../msq";

 // now we can override the getPerson the way we want

 msq.getPerson = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ name: "manas", id: 2 });

 it("user.getUserInfo must resolve the person with id 2",async()=>{

      const result = await user.getUserInfo();
      expect(result).toEqual({name:"manas",id:2});

 });
```

Comment: But what if you don't have control over msq.ts? Can anything still be done in app.ts?

Comment: import everything from msq to another file  and export from that file using export default {} .   It may work !!!